# How best to prepare a uniform superposition over all strings of balanced parentheses?

Tags: state-preparation, stoquatic-matrices

**[0001]** Consider the set $D_n\subset \{(,)\}^{2n}$ of all [Dyck words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language) of strings of balanced brackets or balanced parentheses of length $2n$.  For example, for $n=5$, we have $\sigma=()()()()()$ is balanced, while $\tau=(()))(()()$ is not.

**[0002]** Thought of as basis vectors in a Hilbert space on $2n$ qubits $\{|(\rangle,|)\rangle\}^{\otimes 2n}$, an interesting highly entangled state is the uniform superposition of all such Dyck words.  Indeed, from Sergey Bravyi's lecture on [stoquastic Hamiltonians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By0XTsAk-ic) at the Israeli Institute of Advanced Studies, I learned that Salberger and Korepin [proved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03842) for a fixed $n$ all such Dyck words can be generated with only two moves, each acting on three (adjacent) symbols:

$$l:(()\leftrightarrow ()(,\\
r:\:)()\leftrightarrow ()).$$

**[0003]** With some similarity to a CSWAP involution, such moves are referred to in the literature as Fredkin moves, and the chain of qubits as Fredkin spin chains.  Again fixing $n$ and starting from a string such as $\sigma$, a random walk on the unweighted graph formed by such moves will eventually reach all such Dyck words.  Accordingly, Salberger and Korepin write a three-local stoquastic Hamiltonian out of projectors $|l\rangle\langle l|$ and $|r\rangle\langle r$|.  The appropriately normalized state $|D_n\rangle$ over all Dyck words of a fixed length is the *unique ground state* of the stoquastic Hamiltonian.

**[0004]** It may be natural to ask:

> How can we efficiently prepare such a properly normalized state corresponding to the uniform distribution over all Dyck words on $2n$ qubits?

**[0005]** Determining the balancedness of a string of parentheses is often introduced early in the study of algorithms.  For example, opening and closing parentheses correspond to pushing and popping items onto a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)); the string is balanced only if the stack never experiences underflow.

**[0006]** Also, famously the number of strings of balanced parentheses of length $2n$ is given by the $n$th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), which is:

$$C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n},$$

while the central binomial coefficient is given by $2n\choose n$.  So one approach may be to (1) initially prepare the uniform superposition over all $2n\choose n$ strings with the same number $n$ of open parentheses as closed parentheses, (2) evaluate in superposition and into a flag register if the strings so constructed are balanced or not, for example using the above stack underflow algorithm, and (3) post-select on the flag register indicating that the strings are balanced, with success probability $\frac{1}{n+1}$.  But is there another simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the parent Hamiltonian (the one you describe above) and adiabatically prepare the ground state, by interpolating from a trivial Hamiltonian.

Given the structure of the problem, I would expect such an interpolation can be designed with a 1/poly gap, and thus carried out in polynomial time.

(One idea would be to start with a Hamiltonian where the bracketing patterns are constrained to one end of the chain, and then slowly let them expand -- this path should have a nice and uniform behavior.)

Comment: Indeed, from [Movassagh](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09160) the gap of the parent Hamiltonian is polynomial.

Comment: @MarkS Precisely, for the final state of this and related bracketing models this has been proven by Ramis and coworkers. What I am not entirely sure about is whether one can build an interpolation with a 1/poly(N) gap throughout -- I think it works, but I doubt it has been worked out somewhere.